# Why is it no longer possible to force Chrome to allow user to select download location?

Tags: google-chrome, download

Regardless of the download settings, Chrome now automatically downloads all files to "download location" indicated in the settings, such as printing webpages to pdf or downloading a file from a link on a webpage. Having the box ticked to "Ask where to save each file before downloading" is permanently overridden. It's my hope that someone here can help me to overcome this difficulty. I do not want anything in my downloads folder but new software installation files. Document files, once they download to the Downloads folder become duplicates or are lost. How do I restore normal function to Chrome.

Comment: Is Chrome managed by your organization?  Or is this a personal install?

Comment: I wasn’t able to reproduce the behavior you describe

Comment: It's a personal install on a Windows 10 computer at home. I'm the Admin and only user. 
Example: I find a news or magazine style article on the web. I want to save it using "print to pdf" for use with college students. I set it up, hit "print" and it saves immediately in my Downloads folder. This means I'm stuck with the file at that location until I resave that file to the directory I choose; then I must go back to the downloads folder and look for the original file and delete it. I'd like to be able to do the ordinary thing of choosing where it downloads to begin with. Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Saving the downloads to the folder that I have set works.  However, printing to pdf is a different situation.  On my system, it remembers the last folder I used.  I suspect this is built into the print-to-pdf driver.

Comment: check the registry as described here: https://gearupwindows.com/how-to-enable-or-disable-save-as-prompt-in-google-chrome/

Comment: Works here as well.  Check the setting to ask each time.  I did that and it works fine.  Chrome newest version

Comment: "Saving the downloads to the folder that I have set works." That would indicate that you want all files saved to one particular directory. In my settings I purposefully ticked the box that is supposed to allow me to select the directory to which files are saved every time. It does not say "files will be saved in the download directory despite your setting." So I don't understand the point of the ticked box ignored by the browser. If I could set the "download" folder in the browser to "nil", I would but it does not allow that. If someone can *help* then thank you.

Comment: I changed back and forth between 2 different locations without issue.

Comment: Does that mean you changed back and forth between locations prior to finding something that you wanted to save from the Internet? Or your browser allows you to choose the location each time you save or download something by opening a dialogue box and letting you choose the location? Personally I don't want or need an automatic download location. Nice that others don't have this issue. I still cannot determine the cause of the issue in my browser -  what is causing the browser to bypass the ticked "ask every time"